# How to convert the selected WP7 accent brush to an HTML Color code?

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I have a page that mostly consists of HTML in a WebBrowser control. I was able to set the background quite easily using the PhoneLightThemeVisibility Resource because it's either Black or White.

I was wondering how to get the Accent brush and turn it into a HTML code so I can use it in my HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var brush = (App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush);
string fullColourCode = brush.Color.ToString();
string HTMLColourCode = "#" + fullColourCode.Substring(3);
```

or access the component values individually and build from there....

```
string RedComponent = brush.Color.R.ToString();
string GreenComponent = brush.Color.G.ToString();
string BlueComponent = brush.Color.B.ToString();
```

Note that the red, green and blue component values will need to be manipulated in order to produce and HTML Colour code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the following (assuming that `AppWorkspaceColor` is the one required):

```
Color appColor = SystemColors.AppWorkspaceColor;
string strColorAsHTML = appColor.ToString();
```

Hope this helps.